# StillImage::GetDeviceList Pointer

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, pointers

I'm trying to make a call to a method call called GetDevicesList in an interface called StillIamge and I am getting back empty results.  I think it is a pointer problem but I'm not a C++ expert and I think that is the problem.  The method call is:

```
HRESULT GetDeviceList(
  DWORD dwType,
  DWORD dwFlags,
  [out]  DWORD *pdwItemsReturned,
  [out]  LPVOID *ppBuffer
);
```

I know it is working as when I plug imaging devices in and out eh nubmer of returned devices goes up and down.  The fact that the result is blank I think is due to me not getting the pointers correct - could someone take a quick look and let me knwo if that is the reason please?

```
#include "stdafx.h"

bool debug = true;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    DWORD dwStiTotal = 0;
    PSTI pSti = NULL;
    HRESULT hres = StiCreateInstance(GetModuleHandle(NULL), STI_VERSION, &pSti, NULL);

    STI_DEVICE_INFORMATION deviceInfo[255];
    memset(deviceInfo,0, sizeof(deviceInfo));

    hres = pSti->GetDeviceList(NULL, NULL, &dwStiTotal, (LPVOID*) deviceInfo); 
    printf("number devices %d\n", dwStiTotal);
    for (int i=0; i<dwStiTotal; i++){
        printf("---------------------------------------------------\n");
        printf("type %d\n", deviceInfo[i].DeviceType);
        printf("vendor %s\n", deviceInfo[i].pszVendorDescription);
        printf("device %s\n", deviceInfo[i].pszDeviceDescription);
        printf("portname %s\n", deviceInfo[i].pszPortName);
        printf("PropProvider %s\n", deviceInfo[i].pszPropProvider);
        printf("LocalName %s\n", deviceInfo[i].pszLocalName);
        printf("InternalName %s\n", deviceInfo[i].szDeviceInternalName);
    }
    pSti->Release();

    if (debug){
        char key;
        std::cin >> key;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks very much in advance and sorry for asking such a basic question!

Regards,

Neil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff543784%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for `GetDeviceList`, the last parameter *ppBuffer* is a *(pointer to a)* handle to an *STI-allocated* buffer. You are trying to send it a buffer you allocated yourself, I believe this should even be crashing somehow...

Anyway, here is the proper way to do it

```
STI_DEVICE_INFORMATION* deviceInfo = NULL;
hres = pSti->GetDeviceList(NULL, NULL, &dwStiTotal, (LPVOID*) &deviceInfo);
```

And what we get back is a pointer to an array of `STI_DEVICE_INFORMATION` items, allocated by *STI* itself. Once you are done with it, you need to release it with `LocalFree`.

Comment: The questioner's bad code wouldn't crash.  `GetDeviceList` writes the address of the buffer it allocates to the pointer-sized buffer you supply in the final parameter.  The questioner supplies a much bigger buffer, so there's no problem as far as the API is concerned.

Comment: I thought that it required an array of STI_DEVICE_INFORMATION.  Thanks very much that is working now - you are a star!